# Выпадающий список должен появляться под полем или над ним (в зависимости от расположения элемента на экране)

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Выпадающий список должен появляться под полем или над ним (в зависимости от расположения элемента на экране).Он всегда появляется снизу, даже если снизу экрана мало пространства. Как сделать это?

Это мой код:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("button").click(function() {
if ($('select').attr("isClicked") != "true") {
    $('select').css("display", "block").attr("isClicked", "true");
  }
});

$("select").click(function() {
      if ($('select').attr("isClicked") != "false") {
        $('span').html($('select').val());
        $('select').css("display", "none").attr("isClicked", "false");
      }
    });
    
});
```

```css
div.sector {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 36px;
}

button {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

span {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

select {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sector">
  <button>Выбрать тип</button>
  <span></span>
  <select size="5" id="selID" isClicked="false">
    <option value="A">AAA</option>
    <option value="B">BBB</option>
    <option value="C">CCC</option>
    <option value="D">DDD</option>
    <option value="E">EEE</option>
    <option value="F">FFF</option>
    <option value="G">GGG</option>
    <option value="H">HHH</option>
    <option value="I">IIII</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

---

Я сделал бы это через простой `select` без использование `size`, но там нельзя `option`-ом управлять через стил. Так же не подходит плагини, так как у меня будеть там 3000-5000 строк(плагини зависает).